# How to put a breakpoint using Log.d in android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, tags

```
MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("visit_user_id");





private void sendMessage() {


    String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Send Blank Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
        String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
        messageTextBody.put("message", messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("seen", false);
        messageTextBody.put("type", "text");
        messageTextBody.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        messageTextBody.put("from", MessageSenderId);

        DatabaseReference user_message_key = rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).push();
        String message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();


        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();

        messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);
        messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id, messageTextBody);

        rootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
                messageArea.setText("");
            }
        });

    }
}    





private void fetchMessages() {
    rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, messagesList);
            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
            messagesList.add(message);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I'm trying to make a chat application since months but i'm stuck at a certain point from weeks... The problem is i'm able to fetch the messages i send and display on my listview. But i'm not able to fetch the messages sent by the other user... Everything is getting stored in database but i'm not able to fetch it... Many people suggested me to add a breakpoint and check. I don't know what that means... Can anyone help me out checking that. like where do i put what code for checking the exact problem in the logcat

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `breakpoints` is a common practice when it comes to debugging. You can simply click on the line that you think that it creates to problem, as DimDim explained.

Using a log statement, it means that you can print a meesage directly to the logcat. This is an example:

```
Log.d("TAG", "My message!");
```

You can achieve the same thing using:

```
System.out.println("My message!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should click whit left mouse button as shown here:

[image]

Then Run the application in Debug Mode by click on debug button
[image]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo5PXWnKtQ4) you can find a video how to do it.